# How to convert WMA lossless to FLAC?

Tags: command-line, banshee, convert, wma, flac

I have some CDs that I want to convert to FLAC. Banshee can't find their metadata, but Windows Media Player can.

I figured there are two workarounds:

- Rip all CDs using Windows Media Player WMA-lossless, and batch-convert to FLAC with metadata.
- Tweak Banshee to connect to Windows Media Player metadata sources

Any ideas how to do it? I'm preferably looking for a command-line method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert WMA to FLAC, you could try **soundconverter**, a graphical application, but it allows to add multiple files and directories. It keeps the metadata if the output format supports it. **To install it** enter into your terminal this: `sudo apt-get install soundconverter`

Answer (score 7):

I've used `avconv` with great success. It's a command-line utility and has a vast number of options.

The `avconv` utility is provided by the [libav-tools [image: Install libav-tools]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/libav-tools) package (starting in Ubuntu 12.04). To install that, click that link or run:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

I needed only the most basic conversion of WMA to FLAC (the same as you're asking for). To do that with `avconv`

```
avconv -i <input-filename.wma> <output-filename.flac>
```

For more information, see [`man avconv`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/avconv.1.html).

To convert all WMA files inside a directory, you can use the following script:

```
for file in *.wma; do avconv -i "${file}" "${file%%.wma}.flac"; done
```

Comment: Great answer, however, the `flac` is 10 times larger than the `wma` file...

Answer (score 0):

`ffmpeg` is my tool of choice here.

```
# to convert a single file...
ffmpeg -i file.wav -c:a flac file.flac

# ... or all wma files in the current directory (similar to the avconv answer)
for file in *.wma; do ffmpeg -i "${file}" -c:a flac "${file%%.wma}.flac"; done
```

Comment: ffmpeg and avconv (see Roshan's answer) are essentially the same thing. There was some kind of political split that I do not bother to try to understand.