# I'll have what's she's having: Point Banshee to Windows Media Player's metadata sources

Tags: banshee, cd, metadata, musicbrainz

I have some [CDs that Banshee can't find metadata for](https://askubuntu.com/questions/117858/how-to-convert-wma-lossless-to-flac), but Windows Media Player can. I was considering ripping using WMP and converting to Banshee, but that seems like too much trouble.

Is there a way to give Banshee a fallback from its original metadata source (MusicBrainz)  to whatever Windows Media Player is using?

Comment: WMP uses [AMG](http://allmusic.com) as source for tagging, which is great service but it's not free. I would expect that musicbrainz database is bigger, but I'm not sure

Comment: So I guess I should convert the files.

Comment: I don't use Banshee, but doesn't it have access to freedb database? Alternatively try to tag ripped CD with other player/tagger that has freedb or maybe discogs access

Answer (score 1):

Services like MusicBrainz work because they receive contributions from their users, it's not only a consuming-product.

If MusicBrainz has already provided you with metadata for a lot of your CDs, but has failed for just one, I would kindly recommend you to fill in MusicBrainz the details of your CD, so you can later rip it properly from Banshee and it benefits everyone else.

Comment: I've tried, I've really tried, but MusicBrainz interface is nearly impossible. You can't edit the data you've just entered. You fill in a form, and it's gone if your network fails (no autosave). I've entered 5 CDs and gave up.